# How can I select row by substring respect delimeter in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I have a field pattern (is string).

examples:

```
id | pattern
 1 | car;cat;dog       -> words car cat do
 2 | apple;nocar;carno -> words apple nocar carno
```

So, now, I would like to select all items where pattern contains full word 'car'.

Expected result is:

```
id | pattern
 1 | car;cat;dog
```

because there is car - it should skip words like nocar and carno

Thank you for any help.

Comment: ```WHERE FIND_IN_SET('car', REPLACE(`table`.`pattern`, ';', ','))```. The "words" itself must NOT contain a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Could a simple `LIKE` solve it?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE
    pattern LIKE 'car;%'
    OR pattern LIKE '%;car;%'
    OR pattern LIKE '%;car';
```

Comment: I like to just do `WHERE concat(';',pattern,';') LIKE '%;car;%'`